# Issues while fetching attribute names in Array Struct field during ingesting the data from DynamDB to Hive table in S3

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-glue

I am trying to ingest data from DynamoDB table to Hive table built over S3 using AWS Glue.

The data from Source would look like below -

```
{
 "id": "123",
 "name": "Peter",
 "title": "My List",
 "listItems": [
  {
   "manufacture_date": "2023-01-01",
   "purchase_price": "20.0"
  },
  {
   "manufacture_date": "2023-01-02",
   "purchase_price": "30.0"
  }
 ]
}
```

**Code to ingest the data:**

```
datasource = glue_context.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
                            connection_type="dynamodb",
                            connection_options={"dynamodb.input.tableName": "purchase_list"},
                            transformation_ctx="datasource")
ddb_src_df = datasource.toDF()
ddb_src_df.createOrReplaceTempView("ddb_src_df")


inst_sql = f"""insert overwrite table purchase_list
        select id,
name,
title,
cast(listItems as string) as listItems
from ddb_src_df"""

glue_context.spark_session.sql(inst_sql)
```

I would like to have the Attribute names populated on the table so that I can unnest later from the table. But the above code is returning me without Attribute names like below -

| id | name | title | listItems |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Peter | My List | [{2023-01-01, 20.0}, {2023-01-02,30.0}] |

How can I achieve something like this below?

**Expected output:**

| id | name | title | listItems |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Peter | My List | [{manufacture_date:2023-01-01,purchase_price:20.0}, {manufacture_date:2023-01-02,purchase_price:30.0}] |

*Target table strucuture:*

```
id string
name string
title string
listItems string
```

I wanted to have the struct column listItems as String as the Attribute has potential to add more attributes in the future. Please advice.

Comment: Rather than rely on what show, well, shows, can you try to do a .printSchema() instead?  You will probably find listItems is an array of structs with those field names in.  If so that's probably more useful than converting to strings.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Chris ! I will have to have my target table structure defined with attribute names and their data types in that case. If the list items, in the future, gets added with additional attributes, it would require a table DDL alter which I am trying to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. In your `insert`, replace `cast(listItems as string)` with `to_json(listItems)` and you'll get strings "json-style". You can then remove double-quotes around attribute names and values using `regexp_replace` or something, if needed.

Comment: Thank you ! This worked. Can you please tell me how I can remove double quotes around attribute names?

Comment: Although this is a new question, and probably has been answered on SO multiple times... `regexp_replace(listItems,'\"','')` will replace all occurrences of double quotes in column listItems with zero-length strings.

Comment: I have created another question to extract data on Athena. Would you be able to help?

Comment: You'll need Athena experts to chime in. Alas I'm not one of them...  :))